# How would I go about finding the average of the values I got through fscanf function?

Tags: c, scanf

I've written a code to scan the data from a file, and i need to use the scanned data to get an average value

This is my data

Name                        ID          T1  T2  T3  HW1  HW2  HW3  HW4  PRJ
Abd         AK021425    42  67  50  10  10  10  10  68
Adj         AK021432    27  46  40  1.5  10  10  10  80
Ahml        AK021482    63  45  75  10  10  0  10  70

```c
int main()
{
    FILE *value;
    float t1,t2,t3,h1,h2,h3,h4,p;
    float sumt, avgt, pntt, sumh, avgh, pnth, pmrk, pntp, fmark, tavgmrk;
    char s[50], b[9];


    value =fopen("Project2.dat", "r");
    if (value == NULL){
    printf("Error in file");
    }


    fscanf(value, "%*[^\n]\n");
    while (fscanf(value,"\n%40[^0-9] %s %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g",&s, &b, &t1, &t2, &t3, &h1, &h2, &h3, &h4, &p) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%s %s %g %g %g %g %g %g %g %g\n",s, b, t1, t2, t3, h1, h2, h3, h4, p);

        sumt= t1+t2+t3;
        avgt= sumt/300;
        pntt= avgt*60;
        sumh= h1+h2+h3+h4;
        avgh= sumh/40;
        pnth= avgh*10;
        pmrk= p/100;
        pntp= pmrk*30;
        fmark= pntt+pnth+pntp;

        printf("\nFinal Marks = %g\n\n", fmark);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnG7s.jpg

Abd             AK 021425 42 67 50 10 10 10 10 68

Final Marks = 62.2

Adj             AK 021432 27 46 40 1.5 10 10 10 80

Final Marks = 54.475

Ahml            AK 021482 63 45 75 10 10 0 10 70

Final Marks = 65.1

This is the build i get. I need to add all the final marks in the build and get the average of them. How would i do that?

Comment: Why did you tag `C#`? it looks like you want to tag `C` not `C#`

Comment: Sum up the marks and counts outside of the loop in variables used for calculating the overall average.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As the output of your program is text, it should be posted as such rather than an image.

Comment: How do I sum them up outside the loop? I only get the final marks for the last line when i tried.

Comment: Well, you'd continue doing what you're doing inside the loop for the individual marks, of course. You'd have a separate sum variable and count variable outside the loop to store the necessary information for the overall average.

Comment: Replace each `fscanf` with `fgets` and `sscanf` (not the headings). Never check the result of `scanf` function family with `!= EOF` because any other incorrect value will pass. Check with the *specific* number of items that must be converted, so here it would be, for example, `while(fgets, buf, sizeof buf, value) != NULL) { if(sscanf(buf, "%[]....", ....) != 10) { /* handle error */ } }`.

Comment: How would I sum the final marks outside the loop then? The final marks are all tied to the same variable so it gives me only the last final marks when I tried it

Comment: Are variables in short supply? You can create another one. You can't use the same variable to store two pieces of information concurrently. How would you do this on paper?

Comment: I meant how would I assign each Final Marks to a different variable when the loop assigns them to the same variable? Like how would I assign the final marks for line 1 in one variable, then final marks for line 2 in another variable?

Comment: Why do you need to?

Comment: Could you give me an example of a code to do that? I don't understand

Comment: I've literally given you a pseudocode example below. I don't code C. I found this question because you mistakenly tagged C#.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer this as pseudo code, since I'm not a C programmer, and I've also simplified the problem a little.

```c
// Define current variables
currentSum = 0;
currentCount = 0;
currentAverage = 0;

// Define overall variables
overallSum = 0;
overallCount = 0;
overallAverage = 0;

while (haveMarksToRead)
{
    currentSum = readMarks(); // get t1, t2, and t3 a s a summed value
    currentCount = 300; // you seem to be using this as the "total", so we'll see the count to this
    currentAverage = currentSum / currentCount; // calculate the mean average
    print("Average is " + currentAverage);
    
    // Add these values to the overall sum
    overallSum = overallSum + currentSum;
    overallCount = overallCount + currentCount; 
}

overallAverage = overallSum / overallCount; // calculate the mean average
print("Overall average is " + overallAverage);
```

Another approach would be to take an average of the averages:

```c
// Define current variables
currentSum = 0;
currentCount = 0;
currentAverage = 0;

// Define overall variables
averageSum = 0;
averageCount = 0;
averageOfAverages = 0;

while (haveMarksToRead)
{
    currentSum = readMarks(); // get t1, t2, and t3 a s a summed value
    currentCount = 300; // you seem to be using this as the "total", so we'll see the count to this
    currentAverage = currentSum / currentCount; // calculate the mean average
    print("Average is " + currentAverage);
    
    // Sum up the averageSum
    averageSum = averageSum + currentAverage;
    averageCount = averageCount + 1;
}

averageOfAverages = averageSum / averageCount; // calculate the mean average
print("Overall average is " + averageOfAverages);
```

This should get you the same result, although it might be slightly less accurate.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I am required to use fscanf for this.

Comment: @user you an use whatever you like to read the values. It's simplified pseudo code. If you don't understand what "pseudo code" means I suggest you find out so as to avoid confusion. Surely you can see what needs to be done with regards to variables and loop placement, etc. from this pseudo code?

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it